# Emacs says "Font not available" on pretty much any font spec except XLFD strings

Tags: fonts

I'm trying to customize fonts on Emacs with

```
(custom-theme-set-faces
 'user
 `(org-level-1 ((t (:font "STIXIntegralsUp")))))
```

but it says "Font not available", despite STIXIntegralsUp being one of the fonts listed by `(font-family-list)`.  It only seems to work when I pass it the name or XLFD string of a font visible to `xfontsel`, but that excludes a lot of fonts installed on my system.  In fact, if I go to the GUI menu and click Options > Set Default Font... and pick any named font (I tried about a dozen of them), it will say "Font not available".  How can this be?  Emacs can't use the output of a font selection dialog that *it* created?

I'm at a loss here.  Does this sound like a Emacs config problem?  OS font subsystem problem?  Or am I just misusing font specs?  I'm a long-time Emacs user, but I've always avoided its messy font subsystem, so I might be just missing something really basic.

I'm on Ubuntu 21.10 with Emacs installed through apt.  I did try invoking emacs with `--no-init`.  `system-configuration-options` is

```
--build x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --sharedstatedir=/var/lib
  --libexecdir=/usr/lib --localstatedir=/var/lib
  --infodir=/usr/share/info --mandir=/usr/share/man
  --enable-libsystemd --with-pop=yes
  --enable-locallisppath=/etc/emacs:/usr/local/share/emacs/27.1/site-lisp:/usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp:/usr/share/emacs/27.1/site-lisp:/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp
  --with-sound=alsa --without-gconf --with-mailutils --build
  x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --sharedstatedir=/var/lib
  --libexecdir=/usr/lib --localstatedir=/var/lib
  --infodir=/usr/share/info --mandir=/usr/share/man
  --enable-libsystemd --with-pop=yes
  --enable-locallisppath=/etc/emacs:/usr/local/share/emacs/27.1/site-lisp:/usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp:/usr/share/emacs/27.1/site-lisp:/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp
  --with-sound=alsa --without-gconf --with-mailutils --with-cairo
  --with-x=yes --with-x-toolkit=gtk3 --with-toolkit-scroll-bars
  'CFLAGS=-g -O2
  -ffile-prefix-map=/build/emacs-P5Mppj/emacs-27.1+1=. -fstack-protector-strong
  -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wall' 'CPPFLAGS=-Wdate-time
  -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' 'LDFLAGS=-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions
  -Wl,-z,relro'
```

Comment: Does the font name you provide perhaps need to be a complete name? It looks like you're passing only the name of a font *family*, not the name of a font. Is that what `:font` expects? (I don't know, but that's where I'd start looking...)

Comment: By "complete name", you mean ones like "STIXIntegralsUp Regular", right?  That's basically the name I pick from Options > Set Default Font.  I don't know which type of name `:font` expects either, but both of them give "Font not available".

Comment: I meant a font name like this: `"-*-Lucida Console-normal-r-*-*-14-*-*-*-c-*-iso8859-1"`. But I'm only guessing at what the function expects. (What does its doc or code tell you?) In general, a font family name is not the same as a font name, I believe.

Comment: What does `M-: (frame-parameter nil 'font-backend)` give you? If it's only 'x', then you have something disabling the FreeType font backend, maybe something in .Xdefaults. You can try `emacs -Q`, that will disable loading X resources as well.

Comment: @rpluim You're spot on!  I had an ancient setting in my .Xresources that I added a decade ago without a clue about what I was doing, and then completely forgot about.  Do you mind writing a proper answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @Drew I see what you're saying.  Thanks for clearing up the terminology.  Although this issue turned out to be something else as noted above, it's useful to know.

Comment: @rpluim: Consider adding your comment as an answer. OP: consider accepting that answer. Comments can be deleted at any time, and they're not searchable (here or by googling). Q & A need to stand on their own, to be more helpful. Thx.

Comment: @Drew: done. Jun-Inoue: count yourself lucky, older versions of Emacs used to crash instead of malfunction :-)

Comment: @rpluim Seriously?  That would have made me tear my hair out :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a symptom of something overriding Emacs' default font backend. If the result of

```
M-: (frame-parameter nil 'font-backend)
```

is something like `(x)`, then that's what happening, since it should
be something like `(ftcrhb x)` for recent versions of Emacs under X11.

The cause is usually an old `FontBackend` specification in either your personal or system xresources file, or a site-lisp file setting it. If

```
emacs --no-x-resources
```

fixes the issue, then it's a `FontBackend` specification (often in "~/.Xdefaults" or "~/.Xresources"). If that doesn't fix it, but running without any config at all, ie:

```
emacs -Q
```

fixes it instead, then it's a lisp file loaded by Emacs that's at fault.

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading emacs 26 to 28, fonts only worked properly after I deleted the following font-backend line from init.el :

```
(setq default-frame-alist
      '((width . 180) (height . 52)
        (background-color . "black")
        (foreground-color . "white")
        (font . "Noto Sans Mono-9")
        (font-backend xft x) ;; this line has to go !!
 ))
```

Comment: How does this answer relate to the question? Was the symptom of not-working-properly in your case the same error message as in the question? If so, maybe add that info to your answer. Thx.